Arduino -> bulb brightness
I started learning about electricity. I got myself starter kit from arduino and now I have some question about the basics?
I have one bulb and one resistor connected to arduino in series circuit everything is working fine, but when I add another path, basically I just add another resistor and now circuit is parallel (If i understand correctly ), my bulb shines brighter.
Now, it make sense to me that there is more current flowing in circuit because there is also another pathway for current to flow, but can't wrap my head around why my bulb shines brighter?
EDIT
I am really at the beginning of learning and not sure how to draw this correctly.
But hope this picture helps

My Apologies and thank you very much everyone for helping me.
I am not sure how would I draw this, I hope this pictures will help.

enter image description here


What does "Connected to arduino in series" mean?

This might be more suitable for Electronic Engineering SE. Also please provide more details of your setup.

@VincentThacker probably is right, but even on the Electronics site, you'll need to provide a better description of your two setups. The electronics site provides you with the means to draw circuit diagrams in your question. A picture, as they say, is worth a substantial number of words.

EDIT.

The original answer was meant to deal with incandescent bulb lights
The electric circuit you have graphically represented is not the same as your "physical" circuit: the physical circuit build with Arduino as a (voltage, I presume - I haven't checked the output ports), breadboard, resistors and wires is a voltage generator providing power to a LED and a parallel configuration of two resistors: the difference with the scheme is that the light is not connected in series with a resistor only, as shown in the scheme.
Once you have the constitutive equations of the LED, relating voltage $v_{LED}(i_{LED})$ with current $i_{LED}$, and light intensity $I(v_{LED}, i_{LED})$ you can first solve the circuit and then find the light intensity with different configurations of the resistors.

Answer for a incandescent bulb light.
Light bulb light depends on temperature of the wire, that acts like a resistor. This temperature increases as the dissipated power in the resistor increases, and the dissipated power can be modelled for a Ohm resistor as
$$P = R \, i^2 \ ,$$
being $R$ the resistance of the wire and $i$ the current through it.
In the parallel configuration, the equivalent resistance of the circuit decreases, thus $i$ through the wire increases, and so $P$ and intensity of the emitted light increase as well.
Generalization for a generic light. Given the constitutive equations $v_{LED}(i_{LED})$ and $I_{LED}(v_{LED}, i_{LED})$ (provided by hardware manufacturer - otherwise you could find by yourself), you can first solve the circuit with Kirchhoff law
$$e = R_{eq} i + v_{LED}(i) \ ,$$
to find $i$ as a function of the generator voltage $e$, the equivalent resistance $R_{eq}$ of the configuration of the resistors (made it right and consistent between the physical and numerical models!!!), and the constitutive equation of the LED.
Once you know $i$, you should be able to find $v_{LED}(i)$ and eventually $I(v_{LED}(i),i)$.

The "light bulb" in OP's "starter kit" almost certainly is an LED, and not an incandescent bulb.

If you trace the wires in your actual circuit (not your drawing of a circuit which is different) you see it's two resistors in parallel, then that combination is in series with a LED.
In a circuit with one resistor in series with a LED, the current goes through the resistor and the LED, and this reduces the current (compared to if there was just the LED). If you add another resistor in parallel with the first one, current can go through either of them. Electrons can go through resistor 1 and the LED, or resistor 2 and the LED, so it makes sense that more electrons go through the bulb, than if they all have to go through resistor 1.
The combination of two parallel resistors is equivalent to a single resistor with less resistance than either one. There's an equation for that, but I'm sure you don't want to know it just yet.
